# reading a file line by line and parse each line in a list of string using Java 8 steams

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I`m trying to read from a file line by line , and in the same time , parse the line and store the data in a List of MonitoredData.

MonitoredData has as instance variables : startTime, endTime, activityLabel .

The file looks like this :

```
2011-11-28 02:27:59     2011-11-28 10:18:11     Sleeping        
2011-11-28 10:21:24     2011-11-28 10:23:36     Toileting   
2011-11-28 10:25:44     2011-11-28 10:33:00     Showering   
2011-11-28 10:34:23     2011-11-28 10:43:00     Breakfast   
2011-11-28 10:49:48     2011-11-28 10:51:13     Grooming    
2011-11-28 10:51:41     2011-11-28 13:05:07     Spare_Time/TV
```

I want to read this file and store each of the startTime,endTime,activityLabel in a List of MonitoredData

```
 List<MonitoredData>
```

for example :

```
startTime : 2011-11-28 02:27:59
endTime : 2011-11-28 10:18:11
activityLabel: Sleeping
```

Comment: @holi-java that's like exactly the same data too! damn...

Comment: @Eugene yes, even the data are the same too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should look something like this. First get those lines, then split them by `"\\s\\s+"` (least two spaces), then generate an array of tokens.
For each of those array instances generate a `MonitoredData` and collect that data to a `List`.

```
 Files.lines(Paths.get("/tmp/test.txt"))
            .map(s -> s.split("\\s\\s+"))
            .map(arr -> new MonitoredData(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Obviously do the necessary conversion from `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` to the `Date` you are using.

Comment: thank you, it`s working!

Comment: If all you’re going to do with the stream, is to collect into a `String[]`, you don’t need to use `Pattern.compile(pattern).splitAsStream(s)`, a simple `s.split(pattern)` will do.

Comment: @Holger shoot! I was collecting to list initially...